# how to get the users who reacted with an emoji in a message (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

Please can someone provide an example of how to get the users who reacted with an emoji on a message ?

python - discord.py-rewrite

EDIT :
i started with getting the message and outputing it contents
code :

```
   channel_name = bot.get_channel(735207841572454546)
   msg = await channel_name.fetch_message(id)
   await ctx.channel.send(msg.content)
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO! Could you provide some code with what have you tried so far?

Comment: hey, i really didn't know what to use to get what i want so i didn't write anything

Comment: Do you want the users who reacted with a specific emoji, or all users who reacted with any emoji?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh i want the users who reacted with a specefic emoji

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer :

```
channel_name = bot.get_channel(735222904530141244)
msg = await channel_name.fetch_message(id)
await ctx.channel.send(msg.reactions[0])
reaction = msg.reactions[0]
users = await reaction.users().flatten()
await ctx.channel.send('\n'.join(map(str, users)))
```